# Creating decorators, how to get info of file in eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to make a plugin such that whenever a new specific file is created, having certain properties, such as derived from file contents, then that type of decorator is shown.

I know how to make a basic decorator by extending `org.eclipse.ui.decorator extension`.

But, how to know the info regarding file such as file name and extension before applying a descriptor? I know little that it can be done using `Object element` parameter in `decorate()` method of file implementing `ILightWeightLabelDecorator` interface. But I don't know how to use this `element` object?

Whenever a new file is added to package explorer, then will the decorators be shown by itself or the workbench needs to be refreshed?

*I am using Eclipse 4.5.2*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `enablement` element of your decorator declaration in the plugin.xml says what sort of objects the decorator is enabled for and determines the type of object passed to the decorator.

So if you have:

```xml
    <enablement>
        <objectClass name="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile"/> 
    </enablement>
```

The `element` object on the

```
@Override
public void decorate(final Object element, final IDecoration decoration)
```

call will be an `IFile`. So you just need to do:

```
IFile file = (IFile)element;
```

or to be absolutely sure you deal with adaptble objects use:

```
IFile file = (IFile)Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter(element, IFile.class);
```

`IFile` has methods to tell you all about the file.